# Why Firefox is trying to access .bashrc?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, auditd, snap

This Ubuntu 22.04 installation is fairly new. Why firefox is trying to read .bashrc and many other files. Does this indicate a security breach?

```
[340664.822484] audit: type=1400 audit(1665738538.467:3862): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/home/chris/.bashrc" pid=232464 comm="pool-firefox" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

Comment: No - I'd guess/assume that starting `firefox` does not immediately start the actual firefox binary, but that the firefox command is a wrapper. And that wrapper is a bash shell script -

Comment: a quick search finds https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1982401  *"The problem with the `.bashrc` error is that snaps are normally not allowed to read that file, yet the desktop integration helpers (the desktop-launch file is built embedding https://github.com/snapcore/snapcraft/blob/main/extensions/desktop/common/init inside it) used by chromium and firefox are bash scripts, and when bash is run non-interactively it will try to read the file pointed to by the `BASH_ENV` variable, which in your case is set to `"$HOME/.bashrc"`."*